# Display circles at each point of a set of polylines

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've got a set of `PointCollections` in an `ObservableCollection` which I can display as a set of polylines like so:

```
class A_model
{
    public readonly ObservableCollection<B> = new ObservableCollection<B>();
}
public class AViewModel : BaseViewModel // implements INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private A_Model m_Model = new A_Model;
    public ObservableCollection<BViewModel> Bees {get {return m_Model.Bees;} }
}
class B_Model
{
    public readonly PointCollection Trail = new PointCollection();
}
public class BViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
    private B_Model m_Model = new B_Model();
    public PointCollection Trail { get{ return m_Model.Trail; } }
}
```

XAML code:

```
<!-- DataContext = AViewModel -->
<Grid>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Bees}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BViewModel}">
                <Polyline StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Green">
                    <Polyline.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Polyline}">
                            <Setter Property="Points">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource pointMultiConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="Trail"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Polyline.Style>                        
                </Polyline>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Now, I'd like to display a little circle at each point of each polyline. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I've not tested this but theoretically you can try using some `ItemsControl` to render all the points as circles. Each point is an item and should be rendered as a circle. This solution does not require any code behind:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BViewModel}">
   <Grid>
     <Polyline StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Green" Name="lines">
         <!-- your code unchanged here -->
     </Polyline>
     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Points, ElementName=lines}"> 
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <Canvas/>
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Canvas.Left="{Binding X}"
                      Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}" Fill="Red">
                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                   <TranslateTransform X="-10" Y="-10"/>
                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
             </Ellipse>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     </ItemsControl>
   </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't get this to work though. I think the problem is that `Trail` doesn't have properties called `X` and `Y`.

Comment: @rashmatash that's not the problem. `Trail` is a `PointCollection` and each `Point` is the DataContext of the binding inside `ItemTemplate`, each Point should have `X` and `Y` properties. Please try the code and report any error if possible. Please elaborate more on how it does not work. Is there any error? if yes, what is it? some errors are not thrown, try looking in the ***Output*** window to see them.

Comment: I tried the code and I don't get any errors. The circles simply don't show up. Only the polyline is displayed.

Comment: @rashmatash have you checked in the ***Output*** window?

Comment: Yes, no errors or warnings what so ever. Only loading stuff and treads exiting with code 259 (I'm running in debug build).

Comment: @rashmatash I'm feeling silly. The `Ellipse` should have some `Fill` set (the default is `Transparent`).

Comment: Haha, I see, but I already had set the fill property to green. So that's not it :(

Comment: @rashmatash in fact `Trail` is just raw data, not actual Points of the Polyline (hence you used some Converter), please see the updated code. The Binding should pull data from the `Polyline.Points` not from viewmodel.Trail

Comment: Yes, I now see the circles, so that's some progress, but they're stuck at the upper left corner of the screen.